# Can't create new ipykernel kernel in pipenv on WSL

Tags: python, jupyter, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv, shutil

I'm trying to run the command `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=testenv` inside a pipenv virtual environment so I can have a Jupyter kernel with the correct modules available.

When I run this command, it errors, with the bottom of the stack trace looking like:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 365, in copytree
    raise Error(errors)
shutil.Error: [('/mnt/c/users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/projectname-xHas313j/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/resources', '/tmp/tmpsnos7rgk_kernels/python3', "[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/tmpsnos7rgk_kernels/python3'")]
```

I can navigate to the directory `/tmp/tmpsnos7rgk_kernels` and can see the `python3` file.

One vague *possible* source of an issue I can think of is that the first argument directory, where I'm assuming the kernel should end up, is on the Windows filesystem whereas the `/tmp` directory is in the WSL filesystem.

I'm using Python 3.6.7 in WSL1.

Comment: I can, as a workaround, successfully run `pipenv run jupyter notebook` to have a notebook with the correct module imports, but I want to be able to explicitly set the kernel inside Jupyter ideally.